# Is the ideal of a subring also an ideal for the base ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

The question is in the title : Is the ideal of a subring also an ideal for the base ring?

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts. Have you considered some examples? Have you tried to prove or disprove this?

Comment: Do you require a ring to have a multiplicative identity (most definitions do, but occasionally this is not required). What happens if an ideal contains the identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb Z$ is a subring of $\mathbb Q$, but the ideal $\mathbb Z\subseteq\mathbb Z$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb Q$.

---

Hope this helps.